# calling an mvc controller from a javascript file within a webforms project

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call an MVC controller from a Javascript file inside a webforms project, but whatever url I provide, the Controller method is not being found.

If someone can help me set the url correctly, it would be much appreciated.

Here is the code:
I modified the RouteConfig file to include the namespace of where the Controllers reside:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "WarrantyUI.Controllers" }
            );
        }
```

Here is the JS file I am trying to call the Controller from with all the variations (see the "url" property) - none of them work.

```
function getJournalVoucherData(parms)
{
    //var url = '<%= Url.Action("GetJournalVoucherDataAsync","JournalVoucher") %>';
    //var url = '<%=Page.ResolveUrl("/WarrantyUI/Controllers/JournalVoucher/GetJournalVoucherDataAsync)%>';
    //var serviceBase = '/JournalVoucher/'
  //  url: serviceBase + 'GetJournalVoucherDataAsync',
    $.ajax({
        //url: url,
        //url: '@Url.Action("GetJournalVoucherDataAsync", "JournalVoucher")',
        url: "/WarrantyUI/Controllers/JournalVoucher/GetJournalVoucherDataAsync",
        //url: Url.Content("GetJournalVoucherDataAsync", "JournalVoucher"),
        //url: Url.Content("/WarrantyUI/Controllers/JournalVoucher/GetJournalVoucherDataAsync"),
        //url: "/Controllers/JournalVoucher/GetJournalVoucherDataAsync",
        //url: "/JournalVoucher",
        //url: "/WarrantyUI/Controllers/JournalVoucherController/GetJournalVoucherDataAsync",
        //url: "/WarrantyUI/Controllers/JournalVoucher/GetJournalVoucherDataAsync",
        data: JSON.stringify(parms),
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        success: function (data, textStatus)
        {
            if (textStatus == "success" && data && data.kvs && data.kvs.length > 0)
            {
                $("#JournalVoucherGrid-table").children().show();
                $("#JournalVoucherGrid-table")[0].addJSONData(data);
                $("#JournalVoucherGrid-table > span.grdMsg").hide(); $(".divLoadMsg").hide();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#JournalVoucherGrid-table > :not(.grdMsg)").hide(); $("span.grdMsg", $("#JournalVoucherGrid-table")).html('...').show(); $(".divLoadMsg").hide();
            }
        },
        error: function (data, textStatus, sss)
        {
            alert(cnxError + '\n' + sss); $(".divLoadMsg").hide();
        }
    });
};
```

Here is the Controller file:

```
namespace WarrantyUI.Controllers
{
    public class JournalVoucherController : Controller
    {
        //TODO: Add await keyword when making DB call to retrieve actual data from GetJournalVoucherDataAsync method

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>JsonResult - Grid data</returns>
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetJournalVoucherDataAsync()
        {
```

Lastly, the attached image shows the exact path of where this Contoller method resides, but is not being found:
[image]

[image]

### EDIT

Note that this works fine locally, but once deployed to a web server, the controller path cannot be resolved even though if you look at the images, the path is exactly where it supposed to be and the files physically are there.

Do I need to do anything with IIS on the web server to resolve the paths.

Any other info on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: Try `/JournalVoucher/GetJournalVoucherDataAsync`

Comment: As a side note, it's probably in your best interest not to start `[POST]` methods with `Get`.  That's very misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default ASP.NET MVC will look for Contollers in the `Controllers` folder. It will attempt to find a controller that follows the name `XController` where `X` is the `{controller}` part of the URL matched in your route. Within that controller it will then attempt to find a method that matches the name in the `{action}` part of the route.

The controller you wish to match is `JournalVoucher` and the action you want is `GetJournalVoucherDataAsync` so the URL you actually require is:

```
/JournalVoucher/GetJournalVoucherDataAsync
```

Aside: As @Jonesy points out in the comments it's probably not a good idea to name `[POST]` methods with the `Get` prefix. It will work but it's confusing.

Comment: Wow... I feel like an idiot... I can't believe I didn't try that specific syntax (which I know all along is the right way to go). It completely slipped my mind.....

Comment: I knew I left something out.... This is the way I HAD it and works fine LOCALLY. However, when I deploy to a webserver, it cannot resolve the URL (see second picture in EDIT).

Comment: Do _any_ MVC routes work on your webserver? That sounds like a very different problem to the above - do you have `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>` in your web.config?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this in javascript to get base url of your web application
var baseWebURL = '<%=HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)+HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath%>';

then you can add your controller and action method name to it and pass it to ajax call

Hope this will work for you.
Regrads